# Navigation Bar changes background when Search Controller is visible

Tags: ios, navigationbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm simply setting the background color of navigation bar like this

`navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .orange`

As you can see in the GIF below, it works fine until I scroll down a bit more & the search controller gets shown- the background resets itself then.
This is how I set the search controller

```
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController?.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController?.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

Any idea what's the cause of this or how to avoid it? I want the background to be consistent at all times

[image]

Comment: Did you have find the solution to this? I have exactly the same! In iOS 13.0 this behaviour stopped, but iOS 12.x is still affected. The search bar, when visible,  seems to change the navigation bar background appearance.